# Getting Network client is not a HSQLDB JDBC driver error in broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have installed broad-leaf successfully in Ubuntu 14.0 and running Admin successfully while running site application getting an error as shown below screen shot.

**screenshot of the error**
[image]

Please suggest me to fix the error with proper guidance. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: The software is apparently set up to connect to a different database type. Change the setting to HSQLDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved in the latest version of Broadleaf (5.2.1), you are likely seeing [this issue](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/HSQLDatabaseStarter/pull/1)

Comment: i a using the latest version only but it is showing the error like this

Comment: When does this happen? During startup? And by using the latest, does that mean that in your root pom.xml the `<parent>` element is pointing to 5.2.2.1-GA of `broadleaf-boot-starter-parent`?

Comment: During the startup only this error was came and this error is came in ubuntu12.04 operating system. i have run this in windows it run freely with out any errors.